# What is the possible solution to the Problem?

Tags: problem-solving, homework

**Don't need a complete solution just some guidance on how to solve it.**

> Consider that a person has never been to the city airport. It's early in the morning and assumes that no other person is awake in the town who can guide him on the way. He has to drive in his car but doesn’t know the way to the airport.  Clearly identify the four components of problem-solving in the above statement, i.e. problem statement, operators, solution space, and goal state. Should he follow a blind or heuristic search strategy? Try to model the problem in a graphical representation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not an AI question but an assignment.

Comment: just point me in the direction of how I should solve it. @OliverMason

Comment: @Julia What have you tried so far?

Comment: This assignment is asking you to refer to your notes and understand the differences between e.g. blind strategies and and heuristic strategies. You should also look at examples from your course to see how they are broken down into statement, operators, solution space etc. It is hard to give you pointers without simply writing out the answer, because the key thing you are being asked to demonstrate in this assignment is understanding how to analyse a problem statement with basic principles.

Comment: Perhaps if you could give your starting thoughts for the first part - identifying the components - and explain in more detail where you are stuck. Then someone here might be able to show you how to get past where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi Julia.  Welcome to SE:AI!  Is there a subject heading for this question that would support search for users with similar fundamental problems?  We really need to edit the subject.

Comment: Hello. Could you also provide more context? For example, which course are you following where you had this exercise? Have you tried something so far? What do you understand about the problem and what you don't understand?

Comment: I've answered the question, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here the Solution to the problem from myself

The problem can be modeled in a graphical way as followed:

A person has to reach from one node of a graph to another, and the current distance from the goal is not known.

Problem statement: Find a path between two nodes of a graph where the edge weights or any other kind of heuristic is unknown.

Operator: Operators in this is driving from one crossing/landmark to the next. In graphical sense, this may be said to be traversing an edge between two nodes.

Solution space: A solution in this problem can be termed as a path from his initial point to the airport. Graphically, this means all possible paths from the starting node to the goal node, irrespective of the distance.

Goal state: The goal state is the state upon reaching which, the algorithm may stop and report success. Here, the airport is the goal state.

The person has never been to the airport before, so he doesn't know how close a location is from the airport. In other words, there are no heuristic values to help the man. Thus, the man should opt for a blind search strategy (such as BFS or DFS).

Comment: This like a good attempt to me. If you want detailed feedback on correctness then some variation of this could have been in the question. For instance, you could lead with the statements you are *most* confident in and then say you are stuck or not sure about the rest. Or you could ask about the statements you are least confident in. Regarding this answer, I think you have correctly identified that there is no useful heuristic, and a graph representation seems good. In which case, BFS and DFS look weak because they are tree search algorithms and you have a more highly-connected graph.